# auto increment ID in java console oop

Tags: java

i have 3 types of users in my program, when i want to add them i want the id is auto incremented in my file ,,, i make a switch case where im gonna add the persons ,,, i tried with id = ++count(in code) but it works only for current user (enseignant) when i switch to the other one(etudiant) it begins from 0 not the last id used

```
public void addRecord(Scanner strInput) throws IOException {
    int count = 0; 
     int id;
     boolean isFilled; 

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("adherent_db.txt", true));
    String nom = " ";

    System.out.println("donner le type d'adherent ");
    System.out.println("1)Enseignant\t2)etudiant\t3)visiteur ");
    int c = strInput.nextInt();
    switch (c) {
    case 1:
        Enseignant enseignant = new Enseignant();
           isFilled = false;   // sets false to false
                id = ++count; 
        enseignant.setId(id);

        System.out.println("Enter le nom d'Enseignant: ");
        nom = strInput.nextLine();
        enseignant.setNom(nom);

        System.out.println("Entrer le prenom d'Enseignant: ");
        prenom = strInput.nextLine();
        enseignant.setPrenom(prenom);

        System.out.print("Entrer l'adresse d'Enseignant: ");
        adresse = strInput.nextLine();
        enseignant.setAdresse(adresse);

        Enseignant.getType();

        bw.write(enseignant.toString());
        bw.flush();
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        break;
    case 2:
        Etudiant etudiant = new Etudiant();
             isFilled = false;  // sets false to false
                id = ++count; 
        etudiant.setId(id);
        System.out.println("Enter le nom etudiant: ");
```

how to make an auto increment id for the all users , any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the id with the assignment, like this:

```
 public void addRecord(Scanner strInput) throws IOException {
        int id = 1;
        boolean isFilled;

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("adherent_db.txt", true));
        String nom = " ";

        System.out.println("donner le type d'adherent ");
        System.out.println("1)Enseignant\t2)etudiant\t3)visiteur ");
        int c = strInput.nextInt();
        switch (c) {
            case 1:
                Enseignant enseignant = new Enseignant();
                isFilled = false; // sets false to false
                enseignant.setId(id++);

                System.out.println("Enter le nom d'Enseignant: ");
                nom = strInput.nextLine();
                enseignant.setNom(nom);

                System.out.println("Entrer le prenom d'Enseignant: ");
                prenom = strInput.nextLine();
                enseignant.setPrenom(prenom);

                System.out.print("Entrer l'adresse d'Enseignant: ");
                adresse = strInput.nextLine();
                enseignant.setAdresse(adresse);

                Enseignant.getType();

                bw.write(enseignant.toString());
                bw.flush();
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                Etudiant etudiant = new Etudiant();
                isFilled = false; // sets false to false
                etudiant.setId(id++);
                System.out.println("Enter le nom etudiant: ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, but the most direct and straight-forward way is to make your ID count a `static` variable.

What is a `static variable`?

> Static variable in Java is variable which belongs to the class and 
>       initialized only once at the start of the execution. It is a variable which 
>       belongs to the class and not to object(instance ). Static variables are 
>       initialized only once, at the start of the execution. These variables will be 
>       initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables.
>
> A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
>       A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need 
>       any object
>
> Source: [guru99.com](https://www.guru99.com/java-static-variable-methods.html)

This means there is only one copy in the running JVM, so accessing it from anywhere returns the same value.

It's not thread-safe by itself, but for a simple single-threaded program it should be sufficent.

```
private static int NEXT_ID = 0; // set this to whatever starting ID you want

public static int getNextId() {
    return MyClass.NEXT_ID++; // return the current NEXT_ID and then increment
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
id = MyClass.getNextId();
```